# Heads, Tails... Edge?

Tags: kinematics, elasticity

No Nobel prizes at stake, but just an idle thought and an idle question.

How could one calculate the probability of a flipped coin landing stable on its edge, instead of heads or tails? I assume relevant parameters are coin metal, diameter, thickness, rate of spin, coefficient of elasticity of the material it lands on.

However, I have no idea if an analytical solution is possible. Anyone ever try?

Comment: Same question in Math.SE http://math.stackexchange.com/q/69400/. According to this paper http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.48.2547, 1 in 6000 tosses.

Comment: I could have sworn this question was asked here before, but my searching couldn't find it (maybe it was deleted?)

Comment: There are a lot of other parameters as well, like axis of rotation, precession rate, and nutation. I expect that mass and rigidity would matter as well. The type of coin should also be very important (quarters have slightly rounded and ridged edges while pennies do not). Long story short, there is no way I'm going to spend Christmas break making a theory for this. (I might consider it if a bounty showed up after New Year's though ;P)

Comment: I guessed it might be solved either experimentally or through numerical simulation. However, still no idea if it is possible analytically. Or whether someone has been crazy enough to try

Comment: @Geoffrey are you serious about that? I'm interested...

Comment: @jinawee that 1 in 6000 is for *dropping* a coin and having it land on its edge. If you *flip* the coin, you give it some rotational momentum and, while I'm not actually going to go and do the math myself, I'd bet that this rotational momentum significantly reduces the chance that it will land stably on the edge. The coin can just too easily rotate off the edge

Comment: Dunno but it's historical fact that if you do succeed, you'll be able to hear people's thoughts all day.  (for the children in the audience:  google Twilight Zone)

Comment: @Danu Well, sort of, the theory isn't the hard part: actually getting the data is. I need to think about it, but if I determine that I can write the code for this problem without the project consuming my life, then I'll come back here and let you know. If you don't hear anything from me by January 1, you can take that to mean that I've decided that no amount of reputation would be worth the effort of writing, debugging, and running the simulation to collect the data.